# C# Oauth2 retrieve Auth Code

Tags: google-oauth

I have been working on the process of Oauth2. I am writing a C# win form application. I am trying to figure out if there is a way to do a http request to get the Authorization code instead of a web browser pops up and asks for "Grant Access". If it has to do so, i am wondering how i can pass that code to the program? I am not sure how i get pass that to the console since i am using a C# form app.

```
  public static IAuthorizationState getState(NativeApplicationClient arg)
{
    IAuthorizationState state = new AuthorizationState(new[] {AnalyticsService.Scopes.Analytics.GetStringValue()});
    state.Callback = new Uri(NativeApplicationClient.OutOfBandCallbackUrl);
    Uri authUri = arg.RequestUserAuthorization(state);
    Process.Start(authUri.ToString());
    Console.Write("  Authorization Code: ");
    string authCode = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine();
    return arg.ProcessUserAuthorization(authCode, state);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call a browser control from your app. Once your user successfully logs in to Google and authorizes your app from that browser control, parse the authorization code from the title of the page your browser control is left on.

See here:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_oauth2#OAuth2_Installed_Applications_Flow

> If you set the redirect_uri to urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob, Google's authorization server will return a page to the browser like the one shown below. Your application can then extract the authorization code from the page title.

Be careful to parse the code exactly how they describe to. Then proceed to close the browser control and do what you need to do.